# Copy over network to local user

Tags: c#, file, copy, psexec

I want to copy a file from computer A(with account myAccount@mydomain) to computer B(user@computerB) over the network using c#.
I tried using the standard

```
File.Copy(source,destination)
```

or creating a new cmd process but both seemed not to work.

The problem is that computer B has a local user only (no authorized domain users).
If the function is called from computer A,error will occur that the destination isn't found.
If the function is called from computer B(Impersonating or using exepec),error will occur that the source isn't found.
Is there a solution or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Add your code completely please (with source & destination path sample values).

Comment: hi @Afshin this is the question more detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717873/copy-a-file-over-network-to-a-destination-outside-domain